# XML-parser Why is null being passed into thumb_image?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a NullPointerException in my logcat pointing to the line '       holder.imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_THUMB_URL), holder.thumb_image);
' in the **class LazyAdapter** . Why is null being passed into that line?

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public LazyAdapter(Context contextActivity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    this.context = contextActivity;
    data = d;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView id, title, description, bookingDate, bookingTime;
    ImageView thumb_image;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    resultp = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_list_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        holder.bookingDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_date);
        holder.bookingTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_time);
        holder.thumb_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.id.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_ID));
    holder.title.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_TITLE));
    holder.description.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_ADDRESS));
    holder.bookingDate.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_DATE));
    holder.bookingTime.setText(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_TIME));
    holder.imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_THUMB_URL), holder.thumb_image); //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION HERE
    return convertView;
}
```

}

**ImageLoader class** associated with that **function DisplayImage**:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
             android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_height="50dip" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Menu name -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="@string/book_name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Description -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_below="@id/menu_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="@string/book_address"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <!-- Price -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/menu_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/book_date"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/book_date"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/book_time"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       > </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890): Process: com.example.clinicbooker, PID: 890
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.example.clinicbooker.LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:75)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-02 12:30:33.210: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your Stacktrace.

Comment: Updated! Logcat is provided.

Answer (score 0):

`holder.imageLoader` is not `Initialized` in your `getView` method.

`holder` is a `instance` of `ViewHolder` `Class` and imageLoader within the ViewHolder class `not initialized`.

Comment: But it is initialized in the ViewHolder class.

Comment: You Initialized the imageloader thats okay but it is not part of holder right?

Comment: imageLoader is of type ImageLoader(my ImageLoader). I defined this in ViewHolder. And holder is of type ViewHolder. Wow what a chain, sorry I'm quite new to Java.

Comment: still imageloader within the holder not initialized, if you have doubt try to check imageloader not null .

Comment: Yes, it is null. So what can I do to initialize imageLoader , just make an instance of it in the ViewHolder class?

Comment: Then how will you add that to your custom adapter? You should add that into your container right then only you can able to view right?

Comment: I don't understand the point you're trying to make. Which container? imageLoader is already initialized within ViewHolder and used throughout getView. It is of type ImageLoader. So how is imageLoader within ViewHolder not initialized as you say?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_THUMB_URL), holder.thumb_image);
```

instead of

```
holder.imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(BookScreen.KEY_THUMB_URL), holder.thumb_image);
```